# Creating timestamps from an audio file with timestamps

Tags: python, timestamp, text-to-speech

I am making a project where I need to be able to generate timestamps from an audio file. I am using Coqui TTS with Python to generate an audio file from a transcript. I would like to find the timestamps of each word spoken.

The specific model that I'm using in Coqui has a strange accent that makes it difficult for STT modules to determine the correct words.

How could I get the timestamps of each word from an audio file and a transcript?